# Angular/Breeze: How to send a notification from server to client?

Tags: angularjs, notifications, breeze

I have a long processing function to run on server from angular client using breeze. I'd like to send a notification to the client to give a progress update. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your technology stack and your web application scalability requirements. It is easier for you to make your client poll the status from the server from time to time to retrieve the progress you are after. If you want effecient polling then go for something like SignalR / socket.io which will help you a lot with realtime communication with the server side of your code.